# SpriteKit border does not fit real iOS screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I am getting used to sprite kit and attempted to make a simple physical border around the frame of the device which a sprite would bounce on.

However when running the app my iPhone XR the physical borders are way below the actual frame of the device.  I know this because when the ball bounces go below the frame of the actual device and finally bounces up just a bit meaning the borders are below as well.

Here is my code.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    
    var player:SKSpriteNode!
    
    var scoreLabel:SKLabelNode!
    var score:Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        }
    }
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemOrange
        
        
        
        player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
        
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: player.size.height / 2)
        
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
        
        player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
        
        self.addChild(player)
        
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -9.8)
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        
        scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Score: 0")
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        scoreLabel.fontName = "AmericanTypeWriter-Bold"
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 36
        scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.black
        score = 0
        
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)
        
        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
         //create variable representing the frame or border of the gamescene
        
         border.friction = 0 //we don't want friction to the borders
        border.restitution = 1 //we want bouncyness to the borders
        
         self.physicsBody = border
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it.

In GameViewController.swift add this line of code

```
    scene.size = view.bounds.size
```

This will be under the default code of

```
   scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
```